# GitHub: search for a commit with a unique commit hash

Tags: github

Currently, when searching for a commit on GitHub, like [this](https://github.com/search?q=sched%2Ffair%3A+Remove+meaningless+imbalance+calculation&type=commits&p=2), it spews out a bunch of commits with the same hash. This is how it looks like: [search results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fjGc.png)

I want to only search for commits that are unique by the commit hash. Is that possible?